# Move last character of each line to new column

Tags: awk, sed, cut

Which sed/awk command can I use to cut the last number (and remove delimiter `_`) of each string in column 1 and move it to a new column (column 3)?

For example,

```
$ head -3 test1.bed
HLA:HLA00001_A*01:01:01:01_3503  1
HLA:HLA02169_A*01:01:01:02N_3291 1
HLA:HLA14798_A*01:01:01:03_2903  1
```

Should become:

```
$ head -3 test1.bed
HLA:HLA00001_A*01:01:01:01  1 3503
HLA:HLA02169_A*01:01:01:02N 1 3291
HLA:HLA14798_A*01:01:01:03  1 2903
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)_([0-9]+)(.*)/\1\3 \2/' file
HLA:HLA00001_A*01:01:01:01  1 3503
HLA:HLA02169_A*01:01:01:02N 1 3291
HLA:HLA14798_A*01:01:01:03  1 2903
```

The above will work with OSX sed and newer GNU seds where -E = Extended Regexps. With any sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)_\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)/\1\3 \2/' file
HLA:HLA00001_A*01:01:01:01  1 3503
HLA:HLA02169_A*01:01:01:02N 1 3291
HLA:HLA14798_A*01:01:01:03  1 2903
```

Comment: Sorry, but what would the sed statement be if I wanted to keep the last number, including `_`, in the first column?

Comment: Move the `_` inside the parens just before `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[_ ]' '{print $1"_"$2,$4,$5,$3}' file

HLA:HLA00001_A*01:01:01:01  1 3503
HLA:HLA02169_A*01:01:01:02N 1  3291
HLA:HLA14798_A*01:01:01:03  1 2903
```